# Debian 8 (Live-CD) what is the standard login and password?

Tags: debian

I downloaded debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-standard.iso

When I try to enter in live mode. Debian ask me for a login and password.

I try with root/toor but it dont work.

Anyone knows whats happend?

Comment: While off-topic (probably better in the Unix one) this is the top result for this question.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I had the same question when using the Standard console version. The answer can be found in the Debian Live [manual](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/customizing-run-time-behaviours.en.html#532) under the section *10.1 Customizing the live user*. It says:

> It is also possible to change the default username "user" and the
>   default password "live".

I tried the username `user` and password `live` and it did work. If you want to run commands as *root* you can preface each command with `sudo`

Answer (score 11):

I am using Debian 8 live off a USB. I was locked out of the system after 10 min of inactivity. The password that was required to log back in to the system for the user was:

```
login : Debian Live User
password : live
```

I hope this helps